# Python 3 | PyQt5 - QWebEngineView + urllib + beautifulsoup with Cookies

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, beautifulsoup, urllib, pyqt5

Am trying making to make an app with GUI using PyQt5 which does its things on Instagram. Here's a function that I'm stuck at:

```
def pro_smt(self):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/someonespicture123"
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

        #I use this to check whether the profile is public, and therefore accessible without loggin in.
        self.browserWindow.load(QUrl(url))
        self.browserWindow.show()
```

Problem is, if I enter someones url, who has their account set to only show their pictures to friends only, I get a "404 not found" error in Python.
So I have to somehow log in, so that I can access these kinds of images.

So my question is how would I import my Cookies from my Chrome browser, and send them with the requests, so that I log in, and ofcourse stay logged in - so that I can either browse the page with QWebEngineView while staying logged in, and do urllib.requests without them failing.

Environment: 
Python 3.6.2, PyQt5.9, Windows10x64

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about importing your cookies from Chrome, but you can persist them in your app with the following code.  You'll have to log in once to set your cookies, but the next time you run your app you shouldn't need to again.

```
defaultProfile = QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
defaultProfile.setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile.ForcePersistentCookies)
cookies_path = '/your_app_cookie_path_here'
defaultProfile.setCachePath(cookies_path)
defaultProfile.setPersistentStoragePath(cookies_path)
```